# Changing TFS Release Retention Policy settings

Tags: tfs, release-management

We are TFS 2017 Update 3.

The default TFS Release 'Retention Policy Settings' are as below after a Team Project is created.

[image: Project level Release Retention Settings]

[image: Collection level Build Retention Settings]

While there is a way to specify the retention policy settings for Builds at the TFS Project Collection level, I am wondering if there is a way to do this for Releases as well. For Releases the retention settings are the project level. I am interested to change this setting for each new project.

I don't see a setting at the process templates.

Is this not provided to the users? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the Global release retention policy is just **project level**. There is no project collection level setting.

> If you are using an on-premises Team Foundation Server, you can
>   specify release retention policy defaults and maximums for a **team
>   project**.
>
> Global release retention policy settings can be managed from the
>   Release settings of your team project:
>
> *On-premises:*
>
> ```
> https://{your_server}/tfs/{collection_name}/{team_project}/_admin/_apps/hub/ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-project-admin-hub
> ```

For **Build**  retention policies:

- *Global build retention policy--project collection level*

  -- *Builds of your definition on the Retention tab*

For **Release** retention policies:

- *Global release retention policy--project level*

  *-- Releases of your definition on the Retention tab*

  ---*Environment-specific retention*

More details please take a look at this tutorial: [Global release retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention#global-release-retention-policy)

Comment: Dear Patrick, Thank you. I had read about the retention policy page. Just was wondering where the collection level setting is provided for release definitions.. perhaps this can be provided in later releases..

Comment: @BaskarLingamRamachandran Thanks for your kindly suggestion, will add a related case in VSTS uservoice page.